# Release Annotations not appearing in Application Insights

Tags: azure-application-insights

See the following [Github Issue](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/85815)

I have followed the documentation that can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/annotations) and while I can see the write action for the annotation in the activity log for the AI instance, I'm not seeing anything under performance, users or workbooks.

If anyone has any insight around how to get these to display it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: While the annotations are not appearing in the Portal UI, they do in fact show up via API call to the management interface, so the annotations are getting there just not viewable via the portal. Ideally it would be beneficial if they were viewable via the portal.

Answer (score 0):

As per GitHub thread, only "Deployment" annotations are supported.

Comment: I have responded to that thread in github this morning, the documentation states that you can view annotations in the UI in the performance, users or workbook blades.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/annotations#view-annotations

As far as I can tell from the API and the documentation a "Deployment" annotation isn't a thing. If you have another resource to provide I'm all ears.

Comment: (I'm from Application Insights team which owns Release annotations). You referred to an article which covers release annotations submitted through various approaches (not API). Annotations API used to support more categories. Now only "Deployment" category is supported. We'll update the documentation.

Comment: Are you saying that when you changed to "Deployment" it still doesn't work?

Comment: Your documentation was unclear, the only place where it states category="deployment" is in the code sample, with no other explanation, as it's a string, it would appear that it could be anything. Please see the updated issue on github.

Comment: Yes, as Osvaldo mentioned, we'll update the documentation.

Comment: If you amend your response to include the updated documentation I will mark it as the answer.